# Symbol to string issue

Tags: ruby, string, symbols

Following code fails

```
world = :world
result = 'hello' + world
puts result #=> can't convert Symbol into String
```

Following code works

```
world = :world
result = "hello #{world}"
puts result #=> hello world
```

Why?

Using ruby 1.8.7

Comment: JavaScript is dynamically-typed and loosely-typed, the latter meaning that certain conversions happen for you. (Hence the old `'1'+1=='11'` problem.) Ruby is dynamically-typed but strongly-typed, meaning that (with few exceptions) you need to perform conversions explicitly.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

String interpolation is an implicit `to_s` call. So, something like this:

```
result = "hello #{expr}"
```

is more or less equivalent to this:

```
result = "hello " + expr.to_s
```

As karim79 said, a symbol is not a string but symbols do have `to_s` methods so your interpolation works; your attempt at using `+` for concatenation doesn't work because there is no implementation of `+` available that understand a string on the left side and a symbol on the right.

Comment: you can also do something fun like an implicit to string call on a bunch of various objects in an array `[:hello, "world"].join(" ")`

Comment: And `result = "hello " + expr` is equivalent to `result = "hello " + expr.to_str`

Comment: @Mattias: Except that String's `+` operator checks if the `expr` has a `to_str` method so you get a TypeError rather than a NoMethodError.

Answer (score 5):

The same behaviour would occur if `world` were a number.

```
"hello" + 1 # Doesn't work in Ruby
"hello #{1}" # Works in Ruby
```

If you want to add a string to something, implement `to_str` on it:

```
irb(main):001:0> o = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x134bae0>
irb(main):002:0> "hello" + o
TypeError: can't convert Object into String
        from (irb):2:in `+'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby19/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0> def o.to_str() "object" end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> "hello" + o
=> "helloobject"
```

`to_s` means "You can turn me into a string", while `to_str` means "For all intents and purposes, I am a string".

Comment: Yep. I would normally use the words *coerce* and *convert* to describe those two behaviors, but unfortunately, the word *coerce* already means something different in Ruby and the error message talks about *conversion* in the context of `to_str`. So, in Ruby `to_str` (and `to_int`, `to_ary`, `to_float`) is *conversion* and I simply cannot come up with a good name for `to_s` (`to_i`, `to_a`, `to_f`).

Comment: @Joerg: Thanks! I've removed the word "convert" from my answer as a result of your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

A symbol is *not* a string, and as such it cannot be concatenated to one without explicit conversion. Try this:

```
result = 'hello ' + world.to_s
puts result
```

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, you can always define the method yourself :)

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > class Symbol
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>  def +(arg)
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>    [to_s, arg].join(" ")
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>    end
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>  end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > :hello + "world"
 => "hello world"
```

Comment: ...but of course this doesn't even work for the OP's question of String + Symbol. You'd need to monkeypatch String#+ to perform type conversion.